# Interface e herança para a classe de conexão em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança, interface

Considerando a orientação a objeto, o uso de herança e interface desta forma estaria correto? Porém desta forma, toda solicitação de conexão com o banco de dados será preciso de um novo objeto. Teria alguma forma de acessar estaticamente ou precisaria de um novo objeto criado ao inicializar o sistema utilizando Singleton?

Interface de conexão

```
public interface ConnectionDB {
    public Connection getConnection();
}
```

Classe GenericConnection

```
public class GenericConnection {

    protected static Properties dbProperties = new Properties();    

    public static Properties getDbProperties() {
        if(dbProperties == null){
            try {
                dbProperties.load(new FileInputStream("src/properties/conf.properties"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GenericConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GenericConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return dbProperties;
    }

    public static void setDbProperties(Properties dbProperties) {
        GenericConnection.dbProperties = dbProperties;
    }
}
```

Classe OracleConnection

```
public class OracleConnection extends GenericConnection implements ConnectionDB {

    private Connection conn;
    private Statement st;

    public Statement getSt() {
        return st;
    }

    public void setSt(Statement st) {
        this.st = st;
    }

    public Connection getConn() {
        return conn;
    }

    public void setConn(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (getConn() != null) {
            return getConn();
        } else {
            try {
                String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + getDbProperties().getProperty("ServerOracle") + ":" + getDbProperties().getProperty("portOracle") + ":" + getDbProperties().getProperty("sidOracle");
                setConn(DriverManager.getConnection(url, getDbProperties().getProperty("userOracle"), getDbProperties().getProperty("passwdOracle")));
                setSt(getConn().createStatement());
                return getConn();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(OracleConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É difícil falar em certo, há quem diga que é o mais certo possível, outros dizem que que é desperdício ter que criar objetos novos toda hora.

Particularmente eu faria um Singleton. Mas não sei a necessidade específica. Essa classe é quase um.

Há um erro grave nessa implementação já que a classe mãe só tem membros estáticos, portanto não vai herdar nada.

**Talvez** até fosse o caso de ter tudo estático, mas aí não faria sentido usar herança.

O que eu acho é que essa interface é desnecessária. Me parece que a classe `GenericConnection` deveria ser abstrata e conter o método `getConnection()` sem implementação para deixar a classe concreta resolver isso. Na verdade acho que boa parte do que está na classe derivada poderia estar na classe herdada.

Exemplo:

```
public abstract class GenericConnection {

    private Connection conn;
    private Statement st;

    public Statement getSt() {
        return st;
    }

    public void setSt(Statement st) {
        this.st = st;
    }

    public Connection getConn() {
        return conn;
    }

    public void setConn(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    protected Properties dbProperties = new Properties();    

    public Properties getDbProperties() {
        if (dbProperties == null) {
            try {
                dbProperties.load(new FileInputStream("src/properties/conf.properties"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GenericConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GenericConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return dbProperties;
    }

    public void setDbProperties(Properties dbProperties) {
        GenericConnection.dbProperties = dbProperties;
    }

    public Connection getConnection();
}

public class OracleConnection extends GenericConnection {

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (getConn() != null) {
            return getConn();
        } else {
            try {
                String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + getDbProperties().getProperty("ServerOracle") + ":" + getDbProperties().getProperty("portOracle") + ":" + getDbProperties().getProperty("sidOracle");
                setConn(DriverManager.getConnection(url, getDbProperties().getProperty("userOracle"), getDbProperties().getProperty("passwdOracle")));
                setSt(getConn().createStatement());
                return getConn();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(OracleConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Interface/Connection.java).

Só um exemplo melhorado, não estou dizendo que deve usar exatamente isto.

Comment: Na verdade eu peguei uma classe pronta que eu usava e tentei aplicar a herança sem saber se ia funcionar porque não testei ainda, Eu utilizava tudo estático, mas cada classe eu repetia os atributos e o método getConnection(), eu não gosto de ficar criando objetos a toda hora, como você acha que eu poderia fazer?. Colocar na classe mãe apenas o getConnection() abstrato e o restante nas classes filhas específicas, irei criar uma para o SqlServer e uma para o Oracle.. Na verdade irei criar um pequeno software de controle financeiro para mim como aprendizagem.

Comment: Eu acho que do jeito que eu coloquei pode ser uma forma. Na verdade eu faço de forma bem diferente de todo mundo, mas funciona pra mim ,não ensino outras pessoas fazerem o mesmo.

Comment: Eu não sei se funciona, mas tentei criar vários projetos, por ex. um projeto de acesso ao dao onde está a conexão e todos os daos, e um pacote onde estão as telas de cadastro. Referenciando o projeto dao nas bibliotecas. mas não encontra o arquivo de propriedades, sabe me dizer porque?

Comment: Dá esse erro: jul 27, 2016 9:30:41 AM Conection.GenericConnection getDbProperties
GRAVE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\properties\conf.properties (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado)

Comment: Aí é algum outro problema mais específico. precisa de uma outra pergunta mais específica.

Comment: Verifica se ficou correto da forma que eu fiz.. a OracleConnection https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B91j9PUXTgJscVBUMS1sMlBrZzg/view?usp=sharing / a classe mãe https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B91j9PUXTgJsWDhzd19ma0ptbzA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Vou criar uma outra pergunta mais específica..queria garantir que o restante está correto

Comment: Parece bem melhor, ainda não sei se é o ideal, mas como falei, eu gosto de fazer diferente.

Answer (score 1):

O comentário ia ficar muito grande então acabou virando uma resposta.

Não sei se entendi bem a questão de criar objetos toda hora, mas a não ser que você esteja fazendo operações em lote é melhor que cada operação no banco seja feita por uma `Connection` diferente. Isso porque reaproveitar a mesma conexão para duas operações solicitadas em um intervalo espaçado pode causar *timeouts* indesejáveis.

Sobre a questão da orientação a objetos, eu evitaria criar um DAO genérico do qual os outros DAOs herdam. Tem um [post da Caelum](http://blog.caelum.com.br/como-nao-aprender-orientacao-a-objetos-heranca/) explicando que é um uso de herança desnecessário.

Quanto à forma de se obter as strings de propriedades para criar as conexões, eu preferiria lê-las do arquivo em um código separado e depois passá-las para uma classe `FabricaDeConexoes` via construtor (essa classe teria um método `criarConexao()`), e então passar esse objeto `fabrica` para cada DAO também via construtor do DAO.

Note que não entrei na questão de se ter um *pool* de conexões, que no seu caso pode nem ser necessário.

Aceito críticas e sugestões.

Comment: Então seria interessante a cada conexão com o banco eu criar uma nova conexão, em vez de reaproveitar a mesma em que loguei no sistema. E eu utilizo um controller e um dao abstrato, isso não é interessante?

Comment: Não sei o que falar do controller, aqui estou falando só do acesso aos dados. O seu DAO abstrato está com uma responsabilidade que não é dele. Ele não tem obrigação de acessar o arquivo de propriedades e lê-las. E nem deveria ser, penso eu a principio, responsabilidade da fábrica de conexões.

Comment: Na verdade essas classes da pergunta são de conexões, e não a de acesso ao DAO. Será que eu entendi a sua sugestão?

Comment: Verdade. Não sei de onde eu tirei o DAO. Mas se você estivesse usando um, seria bem apropriado. É uma das coisas básicas que valem a pena aprender. Minha contribuição então é a seguinte: sua OracleConnection deveria ser uma FabricaDeConexoes. A responsabilidade de ler o arquivo não é dela. E para cada operação no banco uma conexão (exceto quando for fazer operações em lote).

Comment: Adicionalmente, estude sobre PreparedStatement (principalmente para evitar ataques de Injeção de SQL) e não capture a SQLException, deixe ela ser tratada pelo nível acima.

Comment: Quando disse nível acima, quer dizer com ThrowsException devolvendo a responsabilidade para o frame, ou que poderia ser?

Comment: Sim, para o frame, se não houver uma camada intermediária. De preferência encapsulada em uma AcessoADadosException, para que não fique evidente que se trata de SQL (a forma como os dados são guardados não importa para a camada de cima).

Comment: valeu, muito obrigado...